# Managed Type equivalent of [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have inherited a dll written in C that I access from a windows application (Framework 2.0) in C#. Recently some machines have been upgraded to 64-bit Windows 7, and the dll is no longer returning the correct values on those machines. I believe this is because the C function has parameter types that are expected to be 64-bit.

Here's the signature of the C function

```
int doFlightCalc_S(double LatA, 
                   double LonA, 
                   double LatB, 
                   double LonB, 
                   int month, 
                   int aircraftCd, 
                   int nbrPsgrs, 
                   int taxiInTm, 
                   int taxiOutTm, 
                   int fuelStopTime, 
                   int *results)
```

Here's the definition that accesses the function from C#

```
[DllImport("doFlightCalc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int doFlightCalc_S(
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double latA,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double lonA,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double latB,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double lonB,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int month,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int aircraftCd,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int nbrPsgrs,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int taxiInTm,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int taxiOutTm,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int fuelStopTime,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [Out] int[] results);
```

If I were to compile the C dll as a 64-bit dll while leaving the function as is, what changes would I need to make to the function in C#?

I would assume that I have to change the I4s to I8s but what type would I replace the int and double with? Would the following :

```
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double lonB,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int month,
```

be changed to:

```
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] (what would go here?) lonB,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)] long (is long correct here?) month,
```

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Without knowing more details, I think you might be prematurely jumping to unwarranted conclusions.  For example, did anybody *recompile* this C .dll?  As a 64-bit binary?  Do you *know* this to be the case?

Comment: No, that's not it.  Nor would you accidentally have created a 64-bit version of that DLL.  Use a debugger.

Comment: I got it working by changing the build platform of the executable from AnyCPU to x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make any changes at all when you compile for 64 bit. The C and C# versions match each other on both 32 and 64 bit.

You seem to think that C int is 8 bytes wide in 64 bit code on Windows. It is not. It is 4 bytes wide.

You can remove all the MarshalAs attributes since they merely re-state the default marshalling.

It seems highly unlikely that the switch from 32 bit OS to 64 bit OS is really the cause of the discrepancy.

Comment: I got it working by changing the build platform of the executable from AnyCPU to x86.

Comment: Under AnyCPU, your managed code would run as a 64 bit process. Which would fail to even load the native 32 bit DLL.

Comment: +1, if only for the "Remove all the MarshalAs since they are redundant"...No need to overcomplicate!

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx ) the enum `UnmanagedType.I8` corresponds to an 8-byte signed integer, or `System.Int64` which is aliased as `long` in C#. My personal preference is to always use the struct type name `Int64` instead of the alias because it just makes me think of bad programming in portable C89 where `long` can mean either a 32-bit or 64-bit integer.

Similarly, `R8` is an 8-byte floating number. The type `System.Double` corresponds to this member.

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] Double lonB,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)] Int64 month,
```

or this, depending on your coding style preferences

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double lonB,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)] long month,
```

However what I don't understand is why 64-bit would make a difference, unless the parameter expects a pointer type (as this is the only primitive type that should be different between 32-bit and 64-bit systems).

**EDIT**: Disregard my answer: I didn't read your question fully. If the C function defines `int` parameters then they will always be the same size regardless of the 32-bit or 64-bit nature of the platform it was compiled for (assuming the same compiler and OS was used for both builds).

Answer (score 0):

`double` would remain a `double`. In C#  `double` is a 64-bit real number, `R8` is a 64-bit real number. `long` in C# is an `Int64` so that would also be the correct type. `I8` is a 64-bit unsigned integer, as is long. However, there's no reason you should be using `I8` because the the values in the C code are all 32-bit integers (C int == I4 == C# int).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree, I was just answering what type `I8` is equivalent to in C#. It doesn't seem like there is any reason to use `I8` instead of `I4` based on the sample code posted.